# Rellenar datos en formulario desde un objeto - Usando Javascript

Tags: javascript

**Javascript** - No sé muy bien cómo **rellenar los campos de datos en el formulario.** Debo introducir un nombre en el campo "`id=nombre`" de mi formulario y pulsar el botón "`Ver`" para ver todos los datos del objeto de ese nombre.

Los datos los guardo en un array. Un objeto tiene los siguientes atributos:

1. Nombre
2. Cantante
3. Año
4. Estanteria
5. Tipo
6. Prestado

**Código de las dos funciones que debo utilizar:**

```
    //Devuelve el objeto Disco que está en la posicion i-esima.
    this.getDisco = function (pos){
        return this.arrayDiscos[pos];
    }

    //Devuelve verdadero si existe el disco cuyo nombre coincide con el que se pasa.
    this.existeDisco = function (nombreRecibido){
        var existe = false;
        for(var i=0; i<this.arrayDiscos.length; i++){
            var nombre = this.arrayDiscos[i].nombre;
            if(nombre == nombreRecibido)
                existe = true;
        }
        return existe;
    }
```

**Código Javascript - evento botón Ver:**

```
document.getElementById('ver').addEventListener('click', verDisco, false);
```

**Código Javascript - verDisco():**

```
function verDisco(){
    var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
    //Comprobamos si existe el disco en nuestra tienda...
    if(miTienda.existeDisco(nombre)){
        //Cargamos los datos del objeto cuyo nombre = nombre en los diferentes campos del formulario.
        //...
        return true;
    }else{
        //Si NO EXISTE ningún disco con ese titulo/nombre, mensaje.
        document.getElementById("errores").innerHTML="NO EXISTE NINGUN DISCO CON EL NOMBRE '"+nombre+"'.";
        document.getElementById("nombre").focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

**¿Cómo puedo acceder a cada atributo del objeto en cuestión?**

Comment: Buenos días;
Estoy haciendo tu pregunta en código , tienes el array con la información para que lo pases por favor?

Comment: ¿Array con información? La información del array la guardo con los datos que introduzco en el formulario, y cuando pulso en GUARDAR, entonces se rellena el array. Seguidamente si ingreso en el campo Nombre: el_nombre_a_buscar, y existe en el array, me rellena TODOS los campos del formulario que ingresé anteriormente.

Comment: Comprendo omaza1990, de igual manera el ejemplo de Jorge Londoño esta bastante claro.

Comment: Pensé que sería más accesible al objeto en cuestion mediante los atributos. Me explico: Si existe un objeto con el nombre "X", sacar todas las propiedades de ese objeto "X". Tantos var propiedad=document.getElementBy("id_cada_campo").value=objeto[X].nombre/cantante/año/estanteria/tipo/prestado; NO?

Comment: Es que el array no lo tengo, no tengo los datos exactos. Lo tengo todo guardado en un array, y dentro del array hay objetos. Pregunto primero si el "nombre" es algún nombre de algun objeto, si se encuentra, pues "despliego ese array-atributo a atributo-; pero no tengo el array declarado de serie: se debe rellenar mediante el formulario.

Answer (score 1):

Si vas a mostrar los datos en el mismo formulario en donde esta el nombre, sencillamente:

```
//Cargamos los datos del objeto cuyo nombre = nombre en los diferentes campos del formulario.

// antes filtras el array por el nombre y devuelves el registro, supongamos en la variable registro

    var data = [{
        Nombre: 'Nombre',
        Cantante: 'Cantante',
        Año: 'Año',
        Estanteria: 'Estanteria',
        Tipo: 'Tipo',
        Prestado: 'Prestado'
}];

 var registro = data.filter(function(record) {
    return record.nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
});

document.<id formulario>.<id text>.value = registro[0].cantante
```

De esta forma puedes rellenar el formulario

Comment: Demasiado complejo lo veo jajaja. ¿Algo más sencillo? Se trata de resolverlo pero también de aprender. ¿Y si al buscar y encontrar el objeto mediante el nombre, creo un Objeto y lo voy recorriendo dato a dato y añadiendo al campo "id" de cada propiedad? No sé si me explico.

Comment: ja ja ja, no es nada complejo, ya tienes tu arreglo, solo filtrarlo para recuperar el nombre que buscaron. Eso te falta y luego pinta los datos en el formulario, son dos pasos solamente ......

Comment: ¿Alguna posible respuesta usando sólamente Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

No, teniendo en cuenta que tu array por decirlo asi esta como un objeto Json debes tomar cada uno de los valores de el y asignarlos a tus objetos html ; ejemplo si tienes el arrary

```
var data = [{
    Nombre: 'Nombre',
    Cantante: 'Cantante',
    Año: 'Año',
    Estanteria: 'Estanteria',
    Tipo: 'Tipo',
    Prestado: 'Prestado'
}];
```

Y tienes en tu Html digamos dos inputs donde vas a cargar la informacion del atributo "Nombre " y "Cantante" podrian ser asi:

```
<input type="text" id="inputNombre"/>
<input type="text" id="inputCantante"/>
```

Ahora para cargar la informacion por medio de jquery es bastante simple , primero obiviamente debes realizar el filtro para encontrar el nombre dentro del array tal como lo tienes en tu codigo y luego de que lo encuentres simplementes le asignas los atributos a los inputs con esta palabra reservada "val()"; o sea hazlo asi:

```
function verDisco(){
   //primero buscas el disco
   if(buscarDisco==true){
    //esto es sintaxis de jquery
    //dentro del val pones el array con la posicion correspondiente y 
      apuntando 
 //al atributo que se va a poner
 $('#inputNombre').val(data[x].Nombre);
 $('#inputCantante').val(data[x].Cantante);

   }else{
alert("Disco no encontrado");
   }
   }
```

Comment: Gracias por la solución pero es solo mediante Javascript como menciona el título... NO se permite ni JSON ni jQuery..

Comment: Además como ya te dije dos veces: ¡¡¡no tengo definido con datos el array, tengo que buscarlos!!! Mi nombre no se llama Raul, ni mi año es el 2014, tengo que buscarlo. No están definidos con datos.