# Cómo extraigo valores de un objeto/array a campos de un formulario

Tags: javascript

**Únicamente utilizando Javascript o DOM,** nada de jQuery, deseo rellenar los campos de un formulario con datos que tengo guardados en un array.

**¿Cómo puedo copiar/rellenar los campos de un formulario con los valores de ese objeto del array?**

Por ejemplo: Si existiera un disco con el nombre "Sarandonga" se mostrarían TODOS los datos de ese disco en su campo correspondiente, bloqueando TODOS los campos salvo el del nombre, por si queremos cambiar a otro disco a ser mostrado.

**Código HTML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="es">
    <head>
        <title>Mi tienda de discos</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/formulario.css" />
        <script src="js/disco.js"> </script>
        <script src="js/tienda.js"> </script>
        <script src="js/formulario.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Tienda de discos</h1>
        <form id="formulario"> 
            <div id="informacion" class="linea_formulario">
            </div>
            <div class="linea_formulario">
                <label for="nombre">Nombre del disco</label>
                <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre"  />
                <div class="limpia"> </div>
            </div>  

            <div class="linea_formulario">
                <label for="cantante">Cantante</label>
                <input type="text" name="cantante" id="cantante"  />
                <div class="limpia"> </div>
            </div>          

            <div class="linea_formulario">
                <label for="anio">Año</label>
                <input type="text" name="anio" id="anio"  />
                <div class="limpia"> </div>
            </div>          
            <div class="linea_formulario">
                <label for="estanteria">Estantería</label>
                <input type="text" name="estanteria" id="estanteria"  />
                <div class="limpia"> </div>
            </div>          

            <div class="linea_formulario">
                <label for="favorito">Tipo de música</label>
                <select name="tipo" id="tipo">
                    <option selected value="none">Elige uno...</option>         
                    <option value="rock">Rock</option>
                    <option value="pop">Pop</option>
                    <option value="punk">Punk</option>
                    <option value="indie">Indie</option>
                </select>                       
                <div class="limpia"> </div>
            </div>

            <div class="linea_formulario">
                <label for="prestado">Prestado:</label>
                <div class="botones">
                  <input type="radio" name="prestado" id="prestado_si" value="si" /><span>Si</span>
                  <input type="radio" name="prestado" id="prestado_no" value="no" checked="checked"/><span>No</span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="linea_formulario">  
                <input type="button" id="guardar" value="Guardar disco" /> 
                <input type="button" id="eliminar" value="Eliminar disco" />
                <input type="button" id="ver" value="Ver disco" />
                <input type="button" id="modificar" value="Modificar disco" />      
                <div class="limpia"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="erorres" id="errores">
            </div>
            <div id="listado" class="linea_formulario">
                Todavía no tienes ningún disco.
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

He realizado las funciones siguientes:

```
function verDisco(){
    var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
    //Comprobamos si existe el disco en nuestra tienda...
    if(miTienda.existeDisco(nombre)){
        //Cargamos los datos del objeto cuyo nombre = nombre en los diferentes campos del formulario.
        return true;
    }else{
        //Si NO EXISTE ningún disco con ese titulo/nombre, mensaje.
        document.getElementById("errores").innerHTML="NO EXISTE NINGUN DISCO CON EL NOMBRE '"+nombre+"'.";
        document.getElementById("nombre").focus();
        return false;
    }
}

    //Devuelve el objeto Disco que está en la posicion i-esima.
    this.getDisco = function (pos){
        return this.arrayDiscos[pos];
    }

   this.existeDisco = function (nombreRecibido){
        var existe = false;
        for(var i=0; i<this.arrayDiscos.length; i++){
            var nombre = this.arrayDiscos[i].nombre;
            if(nombre == nombreRecibido)
                existe = true;
        }
        return existe;
    }
```

Comment: Falta el código del HTML

Comment: Por favor, crea un [mcve]

Comment: ¿Y cómo es esta pregunta diferente de tu otra pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/73132/rellenar-datos-en-formulario-desde-un-objeto-usando-javascript? Las dos parecen tratar lo mismo: cómo poner los valores de un objeto en los campos de un formulario

Comment: @Rubén Código HTML añadido.

Comment: ¿Alguna posible solución?